# Moving points to new coordinates (arcpy.data.editor)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have a versioned enterprise geodatabase. I need to move some points to new locations, which are in the attribute table. This script runs, but it doesn't seem to actually move any of the points.

```
import arcpy
import os

point_fc = r"\\machine\folder\folder\ArcGIS\Connections\db.sde\db.DBO.pointmove"

fields = ['SHAPE@XY', "Longitude", "Latitude"]
with arcpy.da.Editor(os.path.dirname(point_fc), multiuser_mode=True):
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(point_fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = (row[1], row[2])
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've tried your code, it works as expected. Perhaps try CalculateField (arcpy.Point(Longitude,Latitude) on Shape field.

Comment: If you follow up (at the end of the script) with a similar `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` and print out all of the Long/Lat coordinates, do they show the updated or the old coordinates?  How are you verifying that the changes have not worked?